# Profile photos for players in iOS Game Center

Tags: ios, image, game-center, photo

I am working on a certain multiplayer game here and there's a requirement for me to show Game Center profile photos of both, the player as well as the opponent within the game.

I am using Prime31's Game Center plugin, which has the function of loadProfilePhotoForLocalPlayer that fetches your profile image but I am not able to do the same for the opponent.

Please note that I have to show these images within the game UI so I'll have to call the images as Texture2D and show them on planes.

I was able to do it very easily while working on the same game on Android with Google Plus by fetching the playerID through Prime31's PlayGameServices plugin and then passing it to a picasa link, but is there any such link for iOS Game Center as well?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a method that loads player data for an array of playerIDs, with a switch for loading photos.

From the documentation on https://prime31.com/docs#iosGameCenter:

```
// Gets GameCenterPlayer objects for all the given playerIds and optionally loads the profile images asynchronously
public static void loadPlayerData( string[] playerIdArray, bool loadProfileImages, bool loadLargeProfileImages = true )
```

Comment: I did try this, but it never fetched the other player's data. Every time it triggered the LoadPhotoFailed event :(